# Titanium pre-populate SMS body

Tags: javascript, sms, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm opening the native SMS composer in Android and want to pre-populate the SMS body. I tried...

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL('sms:?body=hello world!');
```

....but it adds `hello world!` to the contact field. Is there any way to add to the body?

Comment: for iphone or android?

Comment: I'm testing on an Android but would like to know how to achieve on an iphone too if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for android, you can use intent to send sms...

Example

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
        type : 'vnd.android-dir/mms-sms',
    });
    intent.putExtra('sms_body', <body text>);
    intent.putExtra("address", <number>);
    try {
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Ti.UI.createNotification({
            message : "Error"
        }).show();
    }
```

and for iphone you can use [this module](https://github.com/omorandi/TiSMSDialog) to send sms.

Comment: thanks! I don't want to send the sms in the background. I have to bring up the sms compose view and just pre-populate the sms body.

Comment: The code is good but does not solve the problem. I'm trying to find a way to open the sms compose and populate only the body.

Comment: it is but not populating the SMS body